# Firebase search query not working on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing a search in my android app and I can't seem to make it work.

```
public void loadReleaseData(String name) {
    mDatabase.child("releases")
            .child("europe")
            .child("data").orderByChild("game/name").startAt(name)
            .endAt(name+"\uf8ff")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "New datasnapshot");
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            _Release release = data.getValue(_Release.class);
                            if (release != null) {
                                // No platform filter set add all releases!
                                list.add(release);
                                if (release.getGame() != null) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "NAME: " + release.getGame().getName());
                                }
                            }
                            mUpcomingGamesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

}
```

When I remove `startAt` or `endAt` either of the two data is shown but not the correct data, but when they're both added in, nothing is show and my log "New datasnapshot" doesn't even get printed. I'm searching on the names of the games I have in my database.

My firebase database: 
[image: My database structure]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added it, Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: If you try to hardocde and replace the `name` variable in your method with `SCUM`, does it work?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes hardcoded it and it works

Comment: In this case, the values of those variables are wrong. Have you tested them?

Comment: Yes thank you the values were wrong I had to type the exact name as it appears on the database, and to counter this, I've made inside my game object a new name variable that has the name in lower case and I search based on that after calling name to lower case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, the reason your code was not working was because the value of the `name` variable that was passed to `startAt()` and `endAt` methods was incorrect.
The key for solving the problem is to pass as an argument to both method the exact same `name` that exist in the database, in this case you should search the name in lower case.